# How to use ng2-tree with 100% dynamic content?

Tags: angular

I am building a UI with two instances of ng2-tree, each with a different root node.  The root must be fetched from the database, and all child nodes should be fetched only as the user expands each item.

I tried setting the root node to a temporary value, and then replacing it on init:

```
tree: TreeModel = { value: "Loading..." };
ngOnInit() {
  this.itemService
      .getProject(this.root)
      .subscribe( (item) => this.tree = new ItemTreeNode( this.itemService, 'root', item ) } );
}
```

This only half worked: the name and icon of the root node appeared, but the carat to allow me to expand it never did.

So I tried making a static root node, with the idea that I would hide it, and auto-expand it to fetch the REAL root node:

```
tree: TreeModel = this.rootNode();
rootNode(): TreeModel {
  var self = this;
  return {
    id: 'root',
    value: 'root',
    loadChildren(callback) {
      self.itemService
          .getProject(self.root)
          .subscribe(
            (item) => {
              var node = new ItemTreeNode( self.itemService, 'root', item );
              callback( [ node ] );
            },
            (error) => { console.log( error ); }
          );
    },
    settings: { ... }
  };
}
```

This gave me a root node that I could expand.  When I did, I saw the real root node that I wanted.  However, THAT won't let me expand.  Moreover, I can't figure out how to auto-expand the temporary root node once I hide it.

So, my question is: what is the RIGHT way of populating an `ng2-tree` where the root node is loaded asynchronously?  Should my first approach have worked?

And why can't I keep expanding the dynamically loaded children's children?  Did I do something wrong in my ItemTreeNode class?

```
import { TreeModel,TreeModelSettings } from 'ng2-tree';
import { Item }        from '../model/item';
import { ItemService } from '../shared/item.service';

export class ItemTreeNode implements TreeModel {
  value: string;
  id: string;
  children: Array<ItemTreeNode>;
  icon: string;
  settings: TreeModelSettings;

  constructor(
    private itemService: ItemService,
    private parent_id: string,
    private item: Item
  ){
    this.id = this.parent_id + '::' + this.item.id;
    this.value = this.item.nodeName();
    this.icon = this.item.icon();
    this.settings = {
      templates: {
        node: `<i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg ${this.item.icon()}"></i>`,
        leaf: `<i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg ${this.item.icon()}"></i>`,
        leftMenu: ''
      }    
    };
  }

  loadChildren(callback) {
    this.itemService.getChildrenOf( this.item.id ).subscribe(
      (response) => { 
        var list = response.map( (item) => 
          new ItemTreeNode( this.itemService, this.id, item ) 
        ).sort( (a,b) => {
          var x = a.value;
          var y = b.value;
          return ( x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0 );
        });
            callback(list);
      },
      (error )   => { console.log( error ) }
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I did do something wrong in my ItemTreeNode.

The code, as written, defines loadChildren() *on the prototype* for the object.  The `ng2-tree` is not looking at the prototype, it is looking at the object itself.  I think one could make the case that this is a bug.  But the work-around was easy enough once I understood what was causing it:

Just move the logic up into the constructor and attach it directly to the object, like so:

```
this.loadChildren = (callback) => { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link to get an example of recursive tree -

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-json-viewer-zt6ywd

```
  public categoryModel: TreeModel = {
    value: 'Category tree',
    children: [],
    loadChildren: callback => {
      this.categoryService.getCategories().toPromise()
        .then(result => {
          this.categories = result.data;
          let treeModels: TreeModel[] = [];

          this.categories.map(x => {
            this.treeModels.push({
              id: x.id,
              value: x.name,
              children: this.getSubCategories(x.subCategories)
            });
          });
          callback(treeModels);
        });
    }
  };
```

Comment: This appears to add the children to the tree when the promise is fulfilled.  But it does not appear to meet the original requirement, namely that data is loaded (or refreshed) when a node is expanded.  Am I wrong?